# SharedPreferences does not work for save

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm using `SharedPreferences` to save username but it's not working.

In login `Activity` (read):

```
ocUserName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userNameText);

SharedPreferences prefs = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String userNameKey = "userName";
String userNameTV = prefs.getString(userNameKey,null);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

if(userNameTV != null) {
    ocUserName.setText(userNameTV); 
}
```

in second `Activity` (write):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = 
    getSharedPreferences("com.mesbahsoft.IRIB", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
String userNameKey = "userName";
editor.putString(userNameKey, ocUser);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: You might wanna try [TypedPreferences](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/TypedPreferences).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Activity.getPreferences(int mode)` (as used in your login activity) has a comment:

> Retrieve a {@link SharedPreferences} object for accessing preferences that are private to this activity.

In your second activity you use `Activity.getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)` and provide what looks like your Application Id as the name.

In effect, you are using two different sets of shared preferences in each activity.

I recommend using `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context)` if you intend to use the shared preferences throughout your application.

Comment: Here is a tutorial about how to save, retrieve and clear data using sharedPreferences : http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/android-sharedpreferences-example/

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is that you are unable to read the written value. You need to use the same file in login activity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.mesbahsoft.IRIB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

If this does not work, kindly specify clearly where you are seeing the problem and also specify exceptions seen.

Comment: what exactly is not working? Please be more specific. Are you able to write without errors, get the sharedpref but reading an empty value?

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing different shared preferences in your activities,

`this.getPreferences( Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` is shorthand for `this.getSharedPreferences( <activity's class name>, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

In you login activity, use this,

```
getSharedPreferences("com.mesbahsoft.IRIB", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

References:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences(int)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,int)